# Проблема с подключением прокси: _request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

Tags: python, requests, proxy, aiohttp

пытаюсь сделать get запрос, но получаю ошибку:
_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

```py
       proxies = {'https' : 'socks5://ЛОГ:ПАС@ИП:ПОРТ'}
       print(proxies)
       async with session.get(f'https://{link}',proxies=proxies) as r:
           print('ok')
```

Сессию получаю из предыдущего запроса:

```py
 async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers,connector=connector,timeout=timeout) as session:
```

Получаю ошибку:
_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

В чём проблема?

Пробовал также подключать connector:
_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connector'

Comment: Убрал тег, извиняюсь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оригинальный ответ из документации

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    proxy_auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth('user', 'pass')
    async with session.get("http://python.org",
                           proxy="http://proxy.com",
                           proxy_auth=proxy_auth) as resp:
        print(resp.status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Документайию внимательно читаем. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html?highlight=session.get#proxy-support